# How to create test data for a class that checks for historical data?

Tags: apex, test-setup

I have a class that processes some data returned by a query. The query is based on the createddate column of the object. In this case, the query specifically retrieves data created 3 days before today.

So as an example, the query would have the

`Select Id, Name, Amount__c FROM MyCustomObject__C WHERE CreatedDate = TODAY - 3` as the condition to fetch records.

In my test class any records I insert in the `MyCustomeOBject__c` would always have the `CreatedDate = TODAY`

So how can I make test data that was created 3 days ago?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use following:

```
Test.setCreatedDate(recordId, createdDatetime);
```

Sets CreatedDate for a test-context sObject.

```
Datetime testingday = Datetime.now().addDays(-3);
Test.setCreatedDate(MyCustomObject__c.Id, testingday);
```

Comment: Good answer. I am stuck in another part of my test class. I believe this will solve the issue. Thx.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the below method

```
 Account a = new Account(name='myAccount');

 insert a;

 Test.setCreatedDate(a.Id, DateTime.newInstance(2012,12,12));
```

Comment: What I am suggesting here is that sometimes we have to process very old historical data example previous year 21 Jan data, so giving Dateime.now().addDays(-3) would become difficult to count days, so giving DateTime.newInstance(2012,12,12) is an easier alternative.